# Home viewcontroller is not responding after sign in to the app in swift

Tags: json, swift, uistoryboard

For designing i am using storyboards. Home view controller contains side menu in separate view and i have designed home with collection view. for side menu i am using ENSideMenu which contains MyNavigationController.. if i give MyNavigationController as a is initial view controller then home is working fine but when i give sign in view controller as a is initial view controller then home view controller appears but collection view and side menu is not responding while tapping.

Here is my code:

In appdelegagte:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let userId: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "Uid") 
    print("appdelegate userid \(userId)")
    if userId != nil{
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        self.window!.rootViewController = homeVC
    }
    return true
}
```

in signin vc:

```
func logInService(){

  let parameters = ["username":Int(userIdTextFielf.text ?? ""),
                    "password":passwordTextField.text] as? [String : Any]

    let url = URL(string: "https://dev.anyemi.com/webservices/anyemi/login")
    var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
    req.httpMethod = "POST"
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Contet-Type")
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters as Any, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}
    req.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            // print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {

            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
                print("the json of loginnnnnn \(json)")

                let Uid = json["id"] as? String
                let loginPhoneNum = json["user_id"] as? String
                let nameL = json["user_name"] as? String
                let emailL = json["user_email"] as? String


                let saveUserId: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(Uid!, forKey: "Uid")
                print("the userid is \(saveUserId)")

                if (Uid?.isEmpty)!
                {
                    print("login fail")
                }
                else{

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                        let appDelagate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                        appDelagate?.window??.rootViewController = homeVC

                    }
                }

            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

in home vc:

```
import UIKit

struct JsonData {

var iconHome: String?
var typeName: String?
init(icon: String, tpe: String) {

    self.iconHome = icon
    self.typeName = tpe
}
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


var itemsArray = [JsonData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeServiceCall()

    //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2.0, left: 2.0, bottom: 2.0, right: 2.0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 95, height: 95)
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout  = layout
 }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func sideMenuButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("in side menu")
    toggleSideMenuView()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

    let aData = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.paymentLabel.text = aData.typeName


    if let url = NSURL(string: aData.iconHome ?? "") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
            cell.paymentImage.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
        }
    }



    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MakePaymentViewController") as! MakePaymentViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    let indexPath = indexPath.row

}

//MARK:- Service-call

func homeServiceCall(){

    let urlStr = "https://dev.anyemi.com/webservices/anyemi/getfinancer"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            print("the home json is \(jsonObj)")
            let financerArray = jsonObj["financer"] as! [[String: Any]]
            print("homw financerData \(financerArray)")

            for financer in financerArray {

                let id = financer["id"] as! String
                let pic = financer["icon"] as? String
                let type = financer["tpe"] as! String//dob
                print(id)
                print(type)
                print("the icons \(String(describing: pic))")
                self.itemsArray.append(JsonData(icon: pic ?? "", tpe: type))
                print("online images bug \(self.itemsArray.count)")

            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }
    }).resume()
}

@IBAction func signOutButton(_ sender: Any) {

    print("signout tapped")
    KeychainWrapper.standard.remove(key: "Uid")
}
}
```

if i use MyNavigationController with is initial then sidemenu and didSelectItemAt are working but when i am coming from sinin both are not responding please help me in the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to you are not embedding navigation controller to your HomeViewController. Update your code in sign-in as follow:

```
let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
let appDelagate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
appDelagate?.window??.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Comment: can i send my project to you so that you can understand better.. why because now happening excately opposit to my previous issue

Comment: Yes, you can share via link.